# linux assembly "collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86, linker-errors

I entered the source code on a web site of online coding.

But I got error below the source code.

I think I omitted "main".

Since I learned Intel assmbly, I don't know how to fix it.

Could you help me?

Thank you for helping me in advance.

```
SECTION .DATA
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10
    helloLen:  equ $-hello

SECTION .TEXT
    GLOBAL _START

_START:


; Write 'Hello world!' to the screen
mov eax,4            ; 'write' system call
mov ebx,1            ; file descriptor 1 = screen
mov ecx,hello        ; string to write
mov edx,helloLen     ; length of string to write
int 80h              ; call the kernel

; Terminate program
mov eax,1            ; 'exit' system call
mov ebx,0            ; exit with error code 0
int 80h              ; call the kernel
```

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: `gcc -nostdlib` also make sure you call your entry point `_start` in lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just using *GCC* as a linker and don't care about the *C* runtime then you can exclude it (as Jester pointed out) by passing `-nostdlib` to *gcc* . You then need to provide a `_start` symbol so the code would look like:

```
SECTION .DATA
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10
    helloLen:  equ $-hello

SECTION .TEXT
    GLOBAL _start

_start:
; Write 'Hello world!' to the screen
    mov eax,4            ; 'write' system call
    mov ebx,1            ; file descriptor 1 = screen
    mov ecx,hello        ; string to write
    mov edx,helloLen     ; length of string to write
    int 80h              ; call the kernel

    ; Terminate program
    mov eax,1            ; 'exit' system call
    mov ebx,0            ; exit with error code 0
    int 80h              ; call the kernel
```

You'd assemble and link it like this:

```
nasm -f elf file.asm
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -o file file.o
```

Alternatively you can link directly with `ld` so you could also do this:

```
nasm -f elf file.asm
ld -melf_i386 -o file file.o
```

This would generate a 32-bit Linux executable called `file`

## Using C Library/runtime

Although I don't think the following is what you intended, someone may find the following information useful:

You can use *GCC* and have the *C* library available to your assembly code by renaming `_START` to `main`. The *C* runtime contains an entry point called `_start` that handles initialization and then calls a function called `main`. You can take advantage of the *C* library but `main` has to setup the stack frame correctly and properly clean it up and return when finished since `main` will be treated as a *C* function. The code would look something like this:

```
EXTERN printf    ; Tell the assembler printf is provided outside our file

SECTION .DATA
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10,0 ; Null terminate for printf
    helloLen:  equ $-hello-1          ; Exclude null by reducing len by 1

SECTION .TEXT
    GLOBAL main

; main is now a C function
main:
    push ebp              ; Setup stack frame
    mov  ebp, esp
    push ebx              ; We need to preserve EBX (C Calling convention)

    ; Write 'Hello world!' to the screen
    mov eax,4            ; 'write' system call
    mov ebx,1            ; file descriptor 1 = screen
    mov ecx,hello        ; string to write
    mov edx,helloLen     ; length of string to write
    int 80h              ; call the kernel

    ; Write 'Hello World!' with C printf
    push hello           ; push the address of string to print
    call printf          ; call printf in C library
    add esp, 4           ; Restore stack pointer
                         ; push hello pushed 4 bytes on stack

    mov  eax, 0x0        ; Return value of 0
    pop  ebx             ; Restore EBX
    leave
    ret                  ; Return to C runtime which will cleanup and exit
```

This example uses both `int 0x80` system call to write standard output, and uses *C* `printf` to do the same. You can assemble and link to an executable called `file` with:

```
nasm -f elf file.asm
gcc -m32 -o file file.o
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second one works on the website.

Comment: Could you recommend a book to learn linux assembly? I have read Kip R. Irvine. But it was for INTEL-based computer.

Comment: Well the code you are using is for Intel compatible computers. Maybe you mean that the Kip R Irvine material is for Windows and you are looking for Linux material. I don't actually have any books on the subject so I can't make recommendations, but you might want to consider this online tutorial as a starting point: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/